# What is the word for "eyeing at X and thinking lewd things"?

Tags: word-request

I was thinking of using the word eyeing, but it doesn't necessarily imply that the person eyeing a person X is also thinking about lewd things about person X. Is there a word for this?

For example:

> Bill was ___ her. He found her very attractive indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try **ogling**. It implies looking with lustful intent. When I hear this word it automatically brings to mind the kind of looking you mention.